# Very basic EaseLJS issue. I can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, stage

I'm very new to javascript and EaseLJS but I don't understand how this doesnt work.
I have a html file:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="easeljs-0.7.1.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="game.s.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>  
 <script>
 function init() {
        renderLevel();
    }
 </script>

</head>
<body onLoad="init();">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300">
        alternate content
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

The game.s.js file looks like:

```
function renderLevel()
{

    var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap("brick.png");
    stage.addChild(bitmap);

    bitmap.x = 32;
    bitmap.y = 32; 
    stage.update();   
    alert(stage.canvas);
    alert(bitmap.name);

}
```

The alert I just put there to check the values. stage.canvas rightly points to the HTML5Canvas element but the image won't show!

What am I missing here? :)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the image to stage **before** it loads, then there's no image yet. You need to wait for the image to load before adding it to the stage.

You can do this by using a `preload();` function to load all the images before calling `init();` or `renderLevel();`. Here's what this function should look like:

```
function preload(images, callback) {
    var count = images.length;
    if (count === 0) {
        callback();
    }
    var loaded = 0;
    $(images).each(function () {
        $('<img>').attr('src', this).load(function () {
            loaded++;
            if (loaded === count) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

...and then you can use it like so:

```
preload(["image1.png", "image2.png"], init());
```

[image: JSFiddle Demo]